# Infinite sum: Renormalisation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, path-integral, mathematics, analyticity

Trying to do the calculation made in a physics article [Real-time Feynman path integral with Picard--Lefschetz theory and its applications to quantum tunneling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2386) (page 10 to go from equation 56 to 57), I am facing this sum to solve:

$$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{i\pi}{4}.$$

Using the value of the Riemann zeta function, it is possible to find the value of 
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 1$$
but I don't know if it is allowed, as for convergent series, to just get the $\frac{i\pi}{4}$ out of the sum... I am not very familiar with this technique of "renormalisation" and I have no results to compare with.

I don't know if I had to post it on math-stack exchange so excuse me if I am on the wrong stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

On looking at the paper, I believe that your $e^{i\pi/4}$'s are the $\sqrt i$'s next to the $da$'s. If so, they are absorbed into the normalization ${\mathcal N}$, which  the authors claim coincides with the usual factor.

Answer (score 1):

The linked reference uses the oscillatory Minkowski formulation of the quantum mechanical path integral. Each of the infinitely many modes produces a factor $e^{i\pi/4}$. No rigorous mathematical explanation of their infinite product seems offered in the text other than sweeping it under the rug in form of a normalization constant $\cal N$, cf. mike stone's answer. Nevertheless, the [metaplectic correction](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metaplectic+correction+%28in+geometric+quantization%29)/[Maslov indices](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Maslov+index) in the semiclassical path integral can in principle be deduced via [Wick-rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation) from the Euclidean formulation.